# How to group a collection by a collection?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a collection with a collection that implements many-to-many relationship, here's an example:

```
Student : [
    Name,
    Age,
    Teacher : [
        Name,
        Age
    ]
]
```

I want the students to be grouped by teachers first so I can add the teachers into another collection and then the students. So basically, I want the opposite of the above collection.

```
Teacher : [
    Name,
    Age,
    Student : [
        new Student {},
        new Student {}
    ]
]
```

I already tried this:

```
var teachers = from s in students
               group s by s.Teacher.Name
               into g
               select new { Teacher = g.Key, Students = g.toList()};
```

But it will only return the teacher's `name` and not the whole teacher information.

Comment: Could you add a [mcve], so those of us testing our solutions don't have to write up sample data ourselves, individually?

Comment: If I am not mistaken you can use the whole teacher object wrapped in anonymous object as the key too. So something like this should work:  `... group s by new {  s.Teacher.Name, s.Teacher.Age }` and then `g.Key` would return this anonymous object instead of a single property

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Student> students = new List<Student>();

            var teachers = students.SelectMany(x => x.teachers.Select(y => new { 
                studentName = x.Name,
                studentAge = x.Age,
                teacherName = y.Name,
                teacherAge = y.Age
            }))
            .GroupBy(x => x.teacherName)
            .ToList();
        }
    }
    public class Student
    {

        public string Name { get;set;}
        public int Age { get;set;}
        public List<Teacher> teachers { get;set;}
    }
    public class Teacher
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
class Student
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public Teacher Teacher { get; set; }
    }

    class Teacher
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
```

Assign values :

```
List<Student> Students = new List<Student>()
{
 new Student {Name = "Ron" , Age = 26, Teacher = new Teacher {Name = "Sam",   Age = 26}},
 new Student {Name = "Jon" , Age = 28 ,Teacher = new Teacher {Name = "Andy" , Age = 56}},
 new Student {Name = "Won" , Age = 28 ,Teacher = new Teacher {Name = "Andy" , Age = 56}},
 new Student {Name = "Tol" , Age = 28 ,Teacher = new Teacher {Name = "Andy" , Age = 56}}
};
```

Teacher Sam has one student and Andy has three students.

use LINQ :

```
var teachers = Students.GroupBy(x => new { x.Teacher.Name, x.Teacher.Age} )
                      .Select(gr => new {
                          TeacherName = gr.Key.Name,
                          TeacherAge = gr.Key.Age,
                          students = gr.ToList(),
                      });
```

We have to group by both Name and age in order to get teacher's name and age.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the teacher's names are unique? If you have two Teachers with the same name, are you sure that all other properties are also equal? In that case you don't have to group by Teacher Name, but you can group by the complete Teacher.

Wouldn't it be more efficient to group by Teacher Id?

Anyway, I think you should first flatten the "Students with their Teachers" collection and then group by Teacher's name:

```
TeachersWithTheirStudents = students
    // Flatten the Student with his Teachers into StudentTeacherCombinations:
    .SelectMany(student => student.Teachers,
        (student, teacher) => new
        {
            Student = student,
            Teacher = teacher,
        })
    // GroupBy Teacher name:
    .GroupBy(studentTeacherCombination => studentTeacherCombination.Teacher.Name,
         (teacherName, studentTeacherCombinationsWithThisTeacherName) => new
         {
             // All studentTeacherCombinations of teachers with TeacherName
             // are expected to be equal, so we can just remember the first one:
             Teacher = studentTeacherCombinationsWithThisTeacherName
                       .Select(studentTeacherCombi=> studentTeacherCombi.Teacher)
                       .FirstOrDefault(), // I'm sure there is at least one
             StudentsOfTeacher = studentTeacherCombinationsWithThisTeacherName
                        .Select(studentTeacherCombi => studentTeacherCombi.Student),
         })
         // Finally put this into a Teacher object:
         .Select(teacherWithHisStudents => new Teacher()
         {
             Id = teacherWithHisStudents.Teacher.Id,
             Name = teacherWithHisStudents.Teacher.Name,
             ... // other Teacher properties

             Students = teacherWithHisStudents.StudentsOfTeacher
                        .Select(student => new Student()
                        {
                            Id = student.Id,
                            Name = student.Name,
                            ... // other Student properties
                        })
                        .ToList(),
    });

         });
```